# Can I install a second SQL Server instance on the same location as the first instance?

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation

Can I install a second SQL Server instance on the same location as the first instance? Can that cause some problem?

By the way, I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Great thanks.

Comment: The only issue you might have would be one of resources.  Just make sure your box is beefy enough to handle your requirements.  My last dev box had four instances installed...

Comment: By "same location": do you mean the same machine? Or do you mean installing the SQL Server software into the same directory??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple instances of sql server installed on the same server. Just keep in mind that you will need to use instance name to connect to non default instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can, they say.